# Check for current page is Tag page in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

How to check for a current page tag Page or collection page in Shopify?

Comment: you determine the same using the object named `current_tags`, read more about it [Here](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects#current_tags)